# What does the "leave" mean in "parental leave" and "unpaid leave"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Reading an article on *The Washington Post* I found this:

> "The study pointed out that the United
>   States is the only OECD country that
>   does not have a national paid
>   ***parental leave*** policy. Some states have started to adopt such
>   policies, but most parents are offered
>   ***12 weeks of unpaid leave.***"

The article was about children raised by one parent. I'd like to understand two things here:

1. What does ***parental leave*** policy mean?
2. What does ***12 weeks of unpaid leave*** mean?

The great problem is the word ***leave*** put together with parental.

Comment: as in *leave of absence*, its time off of work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Leave* can be read as *time off*.

*Parental leave* is time off specifically for parents. So a *parental leave policy* is a policy about time off for parents.

The definition of leave as a noun can be found by scrolling down on this page: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/leave

> 2- permission to be absent, as from work or military duty: The firm offers a maternity leave as part of its benefit program.
>
> 3- the time this permission lasts: 30 days' leave

Comment: I believe this meaning of 'leave' derives from "leave of absence", where 'leave' originally meant only "permission", not a specific permission. (No, I don't have a source.)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Understanding "leave" as a noun it becomes clearer.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=leave) is unclear, but suggests that you are right.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, `leave` meaning "permission" is etymologically unrelated to `leave` meaning "go away".  This sense, meaning "time away from duty", came from the first word (since it was originally seen in a military context, where you *really* needed permission), but I'll bet anything it was strengthened by the second (since someone "on leave" in fact leaves).

Answer (score 2):

As reported by the NOAD, *leave*, when used as noun, has two meanings:

- [also "leave of absence"] time when one has permission to be absent from work or from duty in the armed forces
- [often with infinitive] permission

In the reported sentence, the meaning is the first.

> Joe was home on leave.
>   He took a leave of absence last year.
>   He is seeking leave to appeal the injunction.