# Combined reference to multiple leave

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, uncountable-nouns

Dictionaries(dictionary.com, OALD etc.) suggest that ***leave*** (absence from work) is a noun- uncountable, which means it has to be "**leave**" for plural. Also, searching SE to find [Applying/earning/validating leave](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46215/applying-earning-validating-leave) and [What does the "leave" mean in "parental leave" and "unpaid leave"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23133/what-does-the-leave-mean-in-parental-leave-and-unpaid-leave) did not help. The title I used might not be explanatory per se, I couldn't think of a way to better phrase it.

I forwarded a combined leave request to my boss at work for several occasions at once. For instance, I requested for a casual leave on Friday, 6th July and Friday, 13th July and additionally a long planned leave from Wednesday, 25th July till Friday, 24th August.

In reply, the approval e-mail read

> Approved, forwarded ***leaves*** are granted.
>
> **N.B:** Please remain reachable on your cell phone and e-mail during all your
> ***leaves***.

In my understanding, it should still be ***leave***, but somehow ***leaves*** started sounding more correct as the reference was made to several instances of my ***leave*** ([M-W](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/leave+of+absence) illustrates an example and uses it for plural and [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/leave_of_absence) too). Is there a word "*leaves*" for multiple instances of *leave* if combined? Please quote a reference and any other usage.

***Edit**: added references which caused more confusion.*

Comment: Now another question popped up in my head- why is it "Leave(s) of absence" when leave means absence in itself?

Comment: However your boss is a good person in comparison with mine, who doesn't grant me leave as he should do. +1 to the interesting question.

Comment: Your understanding is correct.  The reply has used the word "leave" incorrectly.  It's also poorly punctuated.  I would have written this.  "Approved; the leave you requested is granted."

Comment: @David: Thanks for the response. Is there any reference where it says "leaves" is incorrect? I'm sure the punctuation and grammar are terrible in the approval.

Comment: @Carlo_R.: :D Lucky to have a boss like him. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*[Leave](http://www.learnersdictionary.com/search/leave%20of%20absence)* may be used as a countable or uncountable noun when referring to the period of time one is away from a job.

> Leave of absence is granted. (uncountable)
>
> Leaves of absence are granted. (countable)

Comment: What about the usage of "leave" alone as in my example? Can i still use noun-countable ("leaves")?

Comment: So that makes "leaves are granted" acceptable, that is definitely a new thing for me. Can you please quote any reference.

Comment: "Leave" is simply short for "leave of absence"? They are not the same as I see them. "leave" is taking off and "leave of absence" is more of Permission as @Andrew suggests above.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. I'll wait for other people to post more answers. If i don't find any better explanation, I'll pretty much buy this.

Answer (score 5):

To answer your supplementary question, *leave* in "leave of absence" means *permission*. It also occurs in the phrase "by your leave": "with your permission".

*Leave* has come to mean *absence* in its own right, and to use it to mean *permission* as in the examples in [ODO](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/leave--2) is archaic.